# Why doesn't CodeB prints 42 while CodeA does print 42?

Tags: java, if-statement, break

I'm a beginner. I solved the 1st classical on Spoj. 
But the first code I wrote couldn't solve the exercise because 42 is included in the output. The second code solved the problem because it doesn't print 42. But I still can't figure out how it works. Why does Code A prints 42 and why doesn't Code B? Please help me out!

**Code A**

```
public class CodeA {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 0;
        while(true) {
            if(n!=42) {
               n = input.nextInt();               
               System.out.println(n);
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
       }
   }
}
```

**Code B**

```
public class CodeB {  
    public static void main(String[]args) {

       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

       while(true) {
          int n = in.nextInt();
          if(n == 42) {
            break;
          }
          System.out.println(n);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeA:

```
    while(true) {
        if(n!=42) {
            n = input.nextInt();   // Number is read here
            System.out.println(n); // and unconditionally (always) printed here, 42 or not
        }
        else{
            break; // At next iteration, if last number read was 42
                   // you break out of the "while" loop
        }
    }
```

CodeB:

```
   while(true) {
      int n = in.nextInt();
      if(n == 42) {
        break;    // You break here...
      }
      System.out.println(n); // ... so this is skipped...
   }
   // ... because execution resumes here.
```

Comment: I thought the break, breaks out of the if and continues execution in the while block and therefore would execute System.out.println(n).

Comment: No, that's the problem, `break` applies to loops (`for`, `while`), not to `if`

Comment: So does that mean in CodeA even when the if statement is false, the 2 lines of code within the if block gets executed, which allows 42 to be printed before the program terminates?

Comment: No that's not the reason. In CodeA, the numbers are *always* printed right after scanned. The first time you type 42, it is therefore printed as all other numbers. The difference is at next iteration, the `if` is false, so you go to the `else` and then it breaks. I edited to also explain that.

Answer (score 1):

`break` works for `while`, not for `if`
In **code b** when `n==42` your output `System.out.println(n)` is unreachable.

If you need `n` to be printed when it equals to 42 then you can use

```
if(n == 42) {
   System.out.println(n);
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you expect from **code b** ?

you wrote `if(n == 42)` and put a `break` there ? what does it mean ? doesn't it mean that you want escape ?

Then what it does? it escape when you give input `42`